# QSlider memory leaks?

Tags: qt, qslider

I have Qt 5.0 on linux 64 bit and I noticed something strange. I have small music player. Initially it has 14.4 MB in RAM. But after listen three songs it grow up to 26 MB and still growing. I thought that I have some memory leaks but valgrind show that everything is ok. So I started comment my code and after comment this: `ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(pos);` everything is now ok, my app has always ~14MB in RAM. So I tried with empty project with QSlider only (max 200). Init: 5 MB, sliding to the end: 11 MB. With max 1000 I get almost 20MB. Is this normal that such small and simple control take so much RAM?

Comment: Show some code. Impossible to see what goes wrong otherwise.

Comment: The interesting thing is that there is no code :P . Just drop Slider on form, set max position to 1000, run and move slider to the end. RAM jump from 5 MB to 20 MB. This is only drawing, don't know for what slider need this memory, is it creating object for each position? GTK slider haven't this problem

Comment: Which Qt style do you use?